Rust - как прочитать несколько байт из буффера?
Задача: нужно получить первую строку из файла, либо первые n-байт из файла. Можно это сделать без цикла из буффера? Смысл - получить первую строку, в ней будет дата, на основании анализа этой даты уже либо выполнять цикл и читать весь буффер или не выполнять цикл.
let file_log = PathBuf::from(r"./log");
let input = File::open(file_log).expect("Should have been able to read the file");
let f = BufReader::new(input); 


https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html в документации все есть...

@evo я в этой документации вижу «получить первую строку» (read_line), вижу «получить первые n-байт» (read), но не вижу «получить первую строку либо первые n-байт». Я слепой или это обман?

@andreymal  https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html#method.rewind https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#tymethod.read

@evo вы просто повторили то, что я написал в своём комментарии, а ещё я подозреваю, что вы предлагаете нарушать поставленное в вопросе условие "сделать без цикла из буффера", плюс вы ещё приплетаете дополнительное требование в виде трейта Seek, что не везде уместно. В общем, всё плохо
